# Find the level of Deepest child Treenode

Tags: c#, winforms, recursion, treenode

I have treenode & i would like to find the deepest child in the treenode.
if there are 2 child nodes with `level 11` & `level 13` respectively then i need unction to return me the value 13.

How can i do that ?

```
public int FindLevel(TreeNode oParentNode)
{
   counter++;
  forech(TreeNode oSubNode in oParentNode.Nodes)
  {
    FindLevel(oParentNode);
  }

 return Counter;
}
```

Comment: Homework? And are you using a `TreeView` type of UI component or is this a data structure?

Comment: i have ready treenode & i want to display it in the excel file. How about passing a treenode to a function which will return me the deepest level of node.

Comment: @ Leppie:  sure !! Give me a minute.

Comment: For starters: You need to pass `oSubNode` instead of `oParentNode` inside the loop.

Comment: I will have to compare prev max level with new level every time and if new level is larger, replace older value with new value..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is my suggestion for you:

```
private int GetDeepestChildNodeLevel(TreeNode node)
{
    var subLevel = node.Nodes.Cast<TreeNode>().Select(GetDeepestChildNodeLevel);
    return subLevel.Count() == 0 ? 1 : subLevel.Max() + 1;
}
```

here with explicit types:

```
private int GetDeepestChildNodeLevel(TreeNode node)
{
    var subLevel = node.Nodes.Cast<TreeNode>().Select<TreeNode, int>(subNode => GetDeepestChildNodeLevel(subNode));
    return subLevel.Count<int>() == 0 ? 1 : subLevel.Max() + 1;
}
```

Comment: `var subLevel = node.Nodes.Cast<TreeNode>().Select(GetDeepestChildNodeLevel);` is giving me errors. can u reconfirm the code?

Comment: Sorry, I forget to mention that you have to include a using to `System.Linq`.

Comment: I think its not linq's error..m geting something else..wil paste here

Comment: The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Select<TSource,TResult>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,TResult>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Count<TSource>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: @CodeHippo: It compiles on my machine, please try `return subLevel.Count<int>() == 0 ? 1 : subLevel.Max() + 1;`

Comment: Are you using WPF or WinForms?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the extension method for `TreeView` that returns `Level` of the deepest node in that `TreeView`.

```
public int GetDeepestNodeLevel(this System.Windows.Forms.TreeView treeView)
{
    int level = -1;
    foreach (System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode node in treeView.Nodes) {
        int deep = DigInNodes(node);
        if (deep > level)
            level = deep;
    }
    return level;
}
private int DigInNodes(System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode node)
{
    int level = node.Level;
    foreach (System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode subnode in node.Nodes) {
        int deep = DigInNodes(subnode);
        if (deep > level)
            level = deep;
    }
    return level;
}
```

Code is tested and works for me.

Answer (score -2):

This is the fast way to get level´s deep of selected node.

```
 private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        TreeNode node = treeView1.SelectedNode;
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("You selected: {0}{1}", node.Text,e.Node.Level));

    }
```

Comment: instead of explaining your error, users like downvote, as it happens in real life. OPT asks  to `find the deepest child in the treenode` not `selected node`