# Is there a way to turn a for loop with count into recursive one?

Tags: c#, loops, recursion, tree

I've been doing this task and can't wrap my head around how to convert my for cycle to be recursive one AND find the depth of my tree. Is it even possible to cover all the tree's leaves without a for loop? Because a tree can have many branches and I am not sure how to measure the depth without the loop.

```
static int RecursiveMethodMeasureDepth(Branch branch)
        {
            int value = 1;
            int highestValue = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < branch.Count(); i++)
            {
                value = RecursiveMethodMeasureDepth(branch.GetBranch(i)) + 1;
                highestValue = value > highestValue ? value : highestValue;
            }
            return highestValue;
        }
```

if anyone is wondering about the Branch class, there it is:

```
public class Branch
    {
        private List<Branch> branches;
        public Branch()
        {
            branches = new List<Branch>();
        }
        public void AddBranch(Branch branch)
        {
            branches.Add(branch);
        }
        public Branch GetBranch(int index)
        {
            return branches[index];
        }
        public int Count()
        {
            return branches.Count;
        }
    }
```

I added a picture of a tree bellow and a method that creates same data structure tree:

```
static Branch initializeTree()
        {
            Branch root = new Branch();
            Branch branch2 = new Branch();
            Branch branch3 = new Branch();
            root.AddBranch(branch2);
            root.AddBranch(branch3);
            Branch branch4 = new Branch();
            branch2.AddBranch(branch4);
            Branch branch5 = new Branch();
            Branch branch6 = new Branch();
            Branch branch7 = new Branch();
            branch3.AddBranch(branch5);
            branch3.AddBranch(branch6);
            branch3.AddBranch(branch7);
            Branch branch8 = new Branch();
            branch5.AddBranch(branch8);
            Branch branch9 = new Branch();
            Branch branch10 = new Branch();
            branch6.AddBranch(branch9);
            branch6.AddBranch(branch10);
            Branch branch11 = new Branch();
            branch9.AddBranch(branch11);
            return root;
        }
```

[example of a tree][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqYU2.png

Comment: Anything recursive can be written as a loop and vice versa, because recursion is a form of looping ("code that does something, moves something on so it behaves differently next time it runs, and has a defined stop condition where it ceases being repetitive" - that could be talking either about a loop or a recurse; recurse just uses the method call stack to remember what it has done and is yet to do, loopy approaches may use a collection to remember the past and future, adding future work later in the collection that the current position so it is encountered soon)

Comment: All that said, in this case where your branches could have N branches off themselves it would seem sensible to keep a loop to kick off a recursion that looks through them all, otherwise you're going to have to use recursion to take the place of that loop and it's not going to make the code simpler to understand

Comment: After rereading question multiple times I dont know what you want to achieve. 1. do you want to keep for loop and remove recursion? 2. you want to remove recursion and for loop? 3 you want to keep recursion and remove for loop?

Comment: GOTO statement?  <shudder>

Comment: My take is that the for loop has to go and be replaced with something recursive that enumerates the collection of branches at every level. There will thus be two sets of recursion; one to crawl round the tree branches vertically and one to crawl across branches of each branch. I wouldn't want to write it, debug it or maintain it. For a tree-of-lists is natural/easy to reason about using recursion to travel around the tree parts and looping to travel across the list parts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to avoid having for loop there but keep recursive call you can use LINQ Aggregate:

```
    static int RecursiveMethodMeasureDepth(Branch branch)
    {
        return branch
            .branches
            .Aggregate(1, (depth, b) =>
            {
                var currentDepth = RecursiveMethodMeasureDepth(b) + 1;
                return depth < currentDepth ? currentDepth : depth;
            });
    }
```

Reference
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate?view=net-6.0

Comment: I'm not sure that using LINQ, which is essentially a bunch of "loops that do predetermined things" fits with the spirit of the question..

Comment: @CaiusJard yes question is not clear if issue is for loop or recursive call. I will wait for OP clarification. With some collection of sort, there will always need to be some kind of for loop needed. LINQ makes it more functional a easier to read...

Comment: If the OP does not want to expose the `branches` by a public property, then you can add your solution or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8310752/14171304) one (just change the type) in the `Branch` class itself as class function (say, `GetDeepestBranchLevel()`).

Comment: @dr.null yes i agree placing it in `Branch` class makes lot sense. Where to put this method is design decision.

Answer (score 1):

This suggestion does not use more recursion, but it lets you calculate the depth without using placeholders by utilizing `.Max()` from the System.Linq namespace and sending the current depth as a parameter to the recursive method.

```csharp
//using System.Linq;

static int RecursiveMethodMeasureDepth(Branch branch, int currentDepth = 1)
{
    if (branch.Count() == 0)
    {
        return currentDepth;
    }
    
    return Enumerable.Range(0, branch.Count())
        .Max(i => RecursiveMethodMeasureDepth(branch.GetBranch(i), currentDepth + 1));
}
```

Usage:

```csharp
Branch tree;

//initialize tree

int depth = RecursiveMethodMeasureDepth(tree);
```

---

As suggested by [dr.null](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14171304/dr-null) in a comment to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71948839/is-there-a-way-to-turn-a-for-loop-with-count-into-recursive-one#answer-71949107), such a class-specific method could/should be implemented as a method in the `Branch` class.

Such an implementation could e.g. look like:

```csharp
//using System.Linq;

public class Branch
{
    //Other properties and methods

    public int Depth => GetDepth();
    
    private int GetDepth(int currentDepth = 1)
    {
        if (!branches.Any())
        {
            return currentDepth;
        }
        
        return branches.Max(branch => branch.GetDepth(currentDepth + 1));
    }
}
```

and be called as follows:

```csharp
Branch tree;

//initialize tree

int depth = tree.Depth;
```

Example fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/b7SZP0).